# give some thought to something

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, sentence-structure

Somebody has given his opinion to me on a particular subject. I think about it which raises some questions about that subject matter.

So, I want to say it using the Idioms **"give some thought to something"**

Is the following sentence correct?

> After given some thought to it (your reply) raises some questions.

How can I say it in more natural / native way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence you provided is ungrammatical:

> After giving some thought to it, your reply raises some questions.

This is incorrect because it is suggesting that ***your reply*** was thinking, not you.

You can fix it like this:

> After giving some thought to your reply, I have some questions.
>
> Having given some thought to your reply, I have some questions.
>
> I have given some thought to your reply, and it has raised some questions.